# NP-completeness of testing whether a SAT formula does not contain any redundant clause

Tags: np-complete, np, decision-problem

[This paper](http://frontiersinai.com/ecai/ecai2002/pdf/p0262.pdf) explains that testing the irredundancy of a SAT instance is NP-complete.

But I don't understand the theorem/reduction.

How would one reduce 3SAT or k-SAT to this problem, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi = C_1 \lor \cdots \lor C_m$ be an instance of SAT, where all clauses are non-empty, and $m \geq 2$. We create a new CNF $\psi$ whose clauses are
$$
z_1 \lor C_1, \ldots, z_m \lor C_m, z_1 \lor \cdots \lor z_m,
$$
where $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ are new variables.
Then $\phi$ is satisfiable iff $\psi$ is irredundant.

Suppose first that $\phi$ is unsatisfiable. If $z_1 \lor C_1,\ldots,z_m \lor C_m$ are all satisfied, then necessarily one of the $z_i$ is assigned true, since otherwise we would obtain a satisfying assignment of $\phi$. In other words, the clauses $z_1 \lor C_1,\ldots,z_m \lor C_m$ imply the clause $z_1 \lor \cdots \lor z_m$, which is therefore redundant.

Suppose next that $\phi$ is satisfiable. We will show that $\psi$ is irredundant. Let us first show that $z_i \lor C_i$ is not redundant. Consider an assignment that sets $z_i$ to false, sets all other $z_j$ to true, assigns the variables of $C_i$ such that $C_i$ is falsified, and assigns the remaining variables arbitrarily. By construction, the clauses $z_j \lor C_j$ are satisfied for $j \neq i$ (since $z_j$ is true), and the clause $z_1 \lor \cdots \lor z_m$ is satisfied (since $z_j$ is true for any $j \neq i$). However, the clause $z_i \lor C_i$ is falsified, by construction.

To complete the proof, we show that $z_1 \lor \cdots \lor z_m$ is not redundant. Take a satisfying assignment of $\phi$, and complete it to an assignment for $\psi$ by setting all $z_i$ to false. Then all the clauses $z_i \lor C_i$ are satisfied (since we started with an assignment satisfying $\phi$), but the clause $z_1 \lor \cdots \lor z_m$ is falsified, since we set all $z_i$ to false.

Comment: The paper seems to add an extra variable "a" in the large clause. Isn't it needed? Your explanation seems to work well without it.

Comment: I don't really understand why it's there.

Answer (score 1):

The proof in theorem 1 in [Liberatore'02] shows that irredundancy is NP-hard by reducing SAT to it. Considering any set of non-tautological clauses $\Gamma=\{\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_m\}$ (think of this as the set of clauses of a CNF boolean formula), it builds in polytime a set of clauses $\Pi_\Gamma$ which is irrendundant iff $\Gamma$ is satisfiable (again, $\Gamma$ being satisfiable means the CNF formula $\bigwedge_{j=1}^m \gamma_1$ is). Therefore if you can solve *irredundancy* you can solve SAT.

[Liberatore'02]: Paolo Liberatore. 2002. The complexity of checking redundancy of CNF propositional formulae. In Proceedings of the 15th European Conference on Artificial Intelligence (ECAI'02). IOS Press, NLD, 262–266.

Comment: How is this new set of clauses constructed? New variables and new clauses are introduced, but I struggle to understand the symbols.